# React Native: Expo Auth Session with Google Firebase not working on Android

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform

I am facing an issue with the **Expo Auth Session** in my **React Native Android app** when trying to implement **Google authentication** with **Firebase**. The authentication flow works perfectly on **iOS**, but on **Android**, after selecting an account, the app receives a status code `400 invalid request` from **Google**.

**Problem Description:**

I'm using **Expo Auth Session** with **Google** and **Firebase** for authentication.
The flow that **works on iOS** and **not on Android**:

> Click on the login button -> Redirect to Google and select account ->
> After selecting an account, return status code **400** from **Google**. The
> same flow works **perfectly on iOS**.

**Code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import 'react-native-gesture-handler'
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { PaperProvider, MD3LightTheme as DefaultTheme } from 'react-native-paper';
import Navigation from './navigation';
import * as Google from 'expo-auth-session/providers/google';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-web-browser';
import {
  GoogleAuthProvider,
  onAuthStateChanged,
  signInWithCredential,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from './firebase';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import Home from './screens/Home';

WebBrowser.maybeCompleteAuthSession();

const theme = {
  ...DefaultTheme,
  colors: {
    ...DefaultTheme.colors,
    primary: '#2C6BED',
    secondary: 'tomato',
  },
};

export default function App() {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState(null)
  const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useAuthRequest({
    iosClientId: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    androidClientId: 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com'
  });

  const checkLocalUser = async () => {
    try {
      userString = await AsyncStorage.getItem('bubbleChatUser');
      
      if(userString) {
        const user = JSON.parse(userString);
        setUserInfo(user);
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if(response?.type === 'success') {
      const { id_token } = response.params;
      // console.log('ID TOKEN: ', id_token);
      const credetial = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
      signInWithCredential(auth, credetial);
    }
  }, [ response ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // AsyncStorage.removeItem('bubbleChatUser')
    // checkLocalUser();
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      if(user) {
        // console.log('USER;;;; ', user.stsTokenManager.accessToken);
        setUserInfo(user);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('bubbleChatUser', JSON.stringify(user));
      } else {
        // handle redirect if needed
      }
    });

    return () => unsubscribe()
  }, [])

  return (
    <PaperProvider theme={theme}>
      {userInfo ? <Navigation /> : <Home promptAsync={promptAsync} />}
    </PaperProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**Configuration:**

- Expo version: `49.0.18`
- React Native version: `0.72.6`
- Firebase version: `10.6.0`
- Expo Auth Session: `5.0.2`

**Additional Information:**

- The Android client ID and iOS client ID are correctly configured.
- The signInWithCredential function is used to handle the authentication response.

**Questions:**

- Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Expo Auth Session and Firebase on Android?
- Are there any specific configurations or permissions needed for Google authentication on Android in combination with Expo Auth Session?

I appreciate any insights or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

enable custom URI in google console